# Where can I find adventureworks2012_database.zip?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for adventureworks2012_database.zip the mdf file and the log file. Once downloaded I will be attaching the mdf file. Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express. I downloaded SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/adventureworks/AdventureWorks2012.bak

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@AlexKudryashev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6210773/alex-kudryashev) in the comment section, you can download the AdventureWorks2012.bak file from the below link

https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/adventureworks/AdventureWorks2012.bak

These information we can easily download from Googling itself.